# mysqldump xml format and dbunit expected xml format in phpunit test in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

I am working in phpunit testing with dbunit. This is my first time testing in php.

I am creating xml by this command:

```
mysqldump --xml -t -u username -p database > seed.xml
```

After that as per [doc](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/database.html) xml should be in below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<dataset>
    <guestbook id="1" content="Hello buddy!" user="joe" created="2010-04-24 17:15:23" />
    <guestbook id="2" content="I like it!" created="2010-04-26 12:14:20" />
</dataset>
```

But in my generated xml it looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="demo_app">
    <table_data name="test">
    <row>
        <field name="id">1</field>
    </row>
    </table_data>
    <table_data name="test2">
    <row>
        <field name="id">1</field>
        <field name="name">asdas</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="id">2</field>
        <field name="name">asDASD</field>
    </row>
    </table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

When I am trying to run this in my test class:

```
$this->createMySQLXMLDataSet('seed.xml');
```

I get this error:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Exception: The root element of a flat xml data set file must be called

I am using phpunit 4.1.0 and dbunit 1.3

How can I generate xml in the expected format or how can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The format from the documentation that you reference is for a Flat XML Dataset, which is not what is expected when using `createMySQLXMLDataSet()`.

From your error, though, it seems as if you were actually calling `createFlatXmlDataSet()` by mistake.

You should reference the file you generated with `mysqldump` in a `createMySQLXMLDataSet()` call.